# PowerShell Core Encryption on Linux

Tags: encryption, aes, powershell-core

Is there any way to load Windows PowerShell assemblies or class files into PowerShell Core on a Linux system? I am trying to run a script that calls the *"System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"* class to encrypt a string, but i get the error below:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At /root/Acid/enc/Decrypt.ps1:10 char:19
+ ...    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

This is my PowerShell code initializing the object:

```
function Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    if ($IV) {
        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.IV = $IV
        }
    }
    if ($key) {
        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.Key = $key
        }
    }
    $aesManaged
}
```

Any help welcome, if there is a simpler way to do this, I'd love to know!

Comment: You could investigate the use of Mono to execute the code as a.NET assembly.

Comment: You could try and use `Aes.Create()` instead of directly using an `Aes` implementation class such as `AesManaged`. Let me know if this works!